# Laravel socialite register how can I create unique username for users

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite

How can I create unique username using facebook register socialite laravel, I have the controller code below but I have no idea how it could be, I am new on laravel. Thanks in advance.

```
  public function redirectToFacebook()
    {
       return Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
             'name', 'email', 
        ])->scopes([
            'email'
        ])->redirect();
    } 

    public function handleFacebookCallback()
    {
        try {

            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
            $create['name'] = $user->getName();
            $create['email'] = $user->getEmail();
            $create['facebook_id'] = $user->getId();

            $userModel = new User;
            $createdUser = $userModel->addNew($create);
            Auth::loginUsingId($createdUser->id);

            return redirect()->route('/');

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatinate the timestamp when the user loggs in like:

```
$time = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
$create['name'] = $user->getName().$time;
```

Also each time the user loggs in it will try to create a user so make sure you check first if user exists:

```
public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    try {

        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $create['name'] = $user->getName();
        $create['email'] = $user->getEmail();
        $create['facebook_id'] = $user->getId();

        $user = User::firstOrCreate($create);
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

        return redirect()->route('/');

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Use `firstOrCreate()` function to check if it exists if not then create it .

Comment: thank you for reply, but I would like to create and generate an extra field unique "username"  when users register with socialite facebook. Any idea?